# React - changing the background of a single span class not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fabricjs

I am new to React so my apologies if the question, or the thing I am trying to achieve is just weird (and please do tell if there is a better / more logic way to do this).

I am using the `List` `Fabric React` component in my React application, which is based on the `ListGridExample` component which is found here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/list

I have set it up but I can't seem to accomplish the following:

When a `span class` (which is actually an item) in the `List` component is clicked, I want to change it's `background color`, to do this I have followed the instructions in the following post:
https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/react-js-i-need-a-button-color-to-change-onclick-but-cannot-determine-how-to-properly-set-and-change-state-for-that-component/45168

This is a  fairly simple example but this changes all my `grid cells / span classes` to the color blue instead of only the clicked one. Is there a way I can make just the clicked span class change it's background?

The Initial state:
[image]

The state after clicking one span class (which is wrong):
[image]

**Implementation code (ommitted some unecesary code):**

```
class UrenBoekenGrid extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        bgColor: 'red'
     }

    }

    render() {
      return (
        <FocusZone>
          <List

            items={[
                {
                key: '#test1',
                name: 'test1',
                },
                {
                name: 'test2',
                key: '#test2',
                },
                {
                name: 'test3',
                key: '#test3',
                },
                {
                name: 'test4',
                key: '#test4',
                },

                ..... up to 32 items

            ]}

            onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}

          />
        </FocusZone>
      );
    }


    changeColor(item){
        this.setState({bgColor: 'blue'});

        console.log('clicked item == ' + item.name)

      }



    _onRenderCell = (item, index) => {

        return (
          <div
            className="ms-ListGridExample-tile"
            data-is-focusable={true}
            style={{
              width: 100 / this._columnCount + '%',
              height: this._rowHeight * 1.5,
              float: 'left'
            }}
          >
            <div className="ms-ListGridExample-sizer">
              <div className="msListGridExample-padder">

                {/* The span class with the click event: */}
                <span className="ms-ListGridExample-label" onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, item)} style={{backgroundColor:this.state.bgColor}}>{`item ${index}`}</span>
                <span className="urenboeken-bottom"></span>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    };


}
```

I now have attached the `click event` to the `span class` itself but I would think it is way more logic to have the `click event` on the `item(s)` (array) itself, however I could not find a way to achieve this either.

**----UPDATE----**

@peetya answer seems the way to go since @Mario Santini answer just updates a single cell, if another cell is clicked then the previous one returns back to normal and loses it's color.

So what I did is adding the `items array` to the `state` and adding the `bgColor` property to them:

```
this.state = {
        items: [
            {
                key: '#test1',
                name: 'test1',
                bgColor: 'blue',
            },
            {
                name: 'test2',
                key: '#test2',   
                bgColor: 'blue',    
            },
            {
                name: 'test3',
                key: '#test3',
                bgColor: 'blue',    
            },
            {
                name: 'test4',
                key: '#test4',
                bgColor: 'blue',    
            },
        ],
     }
```

Now in my `List` rendering I have set the items to the `state items` array and added the `onClick` event in the `_onRenderCell` function:

```
render() {
      return (
        <FocusZone>
          <List

            items={this.state.items}

            getItemCountForPage={this._getItemCountForPage}
            getPageHeight={this._getPageHeight}
            renderedWindowsAhead={4}
            onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}

          />
        </FocusZone>
      );
    }


_onRenderCell = (item, index) => {

        return (
          <div
            className="ms-ListGridExample-tile"
            data-is-focusable={true}
            style={{
              width: 100 / this._columnCount + '%',
              height: this._rowHeight * 1.5,
              float: 'left'
            }}
          >
            <div className="ms-ListGridExample-sizer">
              <div className="msListGridExample-padder">

                <span className="ms-ListGridExample-label" 
                     onClick={this.onClick(item.name)} 
                     style={{backgroundColor: item.bgColor}}
                >
                    {`item ${index}`}
                </span>

                <span className="urenboeken-bottom"></span>



              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    };
```

The problem is that I can't add the `onClick event` in the `_onRenderCell` function as this will give the following error:

[image]

I want to keep the Fabric `List component` as it also has functions for rendering / adjusting to screen size, removing the list component entirely and just replacing it with what @peetya suggested works:

```
render() {
        <div>
            {this.state.items.map(item => (
                <div onClick={() => this.onClick(item.name)} style={{backgroundColor: item.bgColor}}>
                    {item.name}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    }
```

But this will also remove the `List` component functionality with it's `responsive` functions.

So my last idea was to just replace the `items` of the `List` with the entire `onClick` div and removing the `_onRenderCell` function itself, but this makes the page blank (can't see the cells at all anymore..):

```
  render() {
      return (
        <FocusZone>
          <List

            items={this.state.items.map(item => (
                <div onClick={() => this.onClick(item.name)} style={{backgroundColor: item.bgColor}}>
                    {item.name}
                </div>
            ))}

            getItemCountForPage={this._getItemCountForPage}
            getPageHeight={this._getPageHeight}
            renderedWindowsAhead={4}
           // onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}

          />
        </FocusZone>
      );
    }
```

I thought that perhaps the css `ms-classes` / div's should be in there as well because these have the height/width properties but adding them (exactly as in the `_onRenderCell` function) does not make any difference, the page is still blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing the background color in the state of the Grid and assign this state to every element of the grid, so if you update the state, it will affect every element. The best would be if you create a separate component for the Grid elements and store their own state inside there or if you want to use only one state then store the `items` array inside the state and add a new `bgColor` attribute for them so if you want to change the background color only for one item, you need to call the setEstate for the specific object of the `items` array.

Here is a small example (I did not tested it):

```
class UrenBoekenGrid extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [
                {
                    key: '#test1',
                    name: 'test1',
                    bgColor: 'blue',
                },
            ],
        };
    }

    onClick(name) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items: prevState.items.map(item => {
                if (item.name === name) {
                    item.bgColor = 'red';
                }

                return item;
            })
        }))
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            {this.state.items.map(item => (
                <div onClick={() => this.onClick(item.name)} style={{backgroundColor: item.bgColor}}>
                    {item.name}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it seems to be the way to go, however I can't seem to implement your solution in my existing `List component`. I have updated my main post (in the update section) with the encountered problems.

Comment: You're welcome :) It seems like you are updating the state in one of the `render()` or `constructor()` functions and it cause infinity loop. Can you please show your constructors and/or render methods?

Comment: There is a chance that this caused the problem: `onClick={this.onClick(item.name)} `. Here you are calling the onClick method when your component get rendered. Try to change it to `onClick={() => this.onClick(item.name)}`

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you once more, replacing the `onClick={this.onClick(item.name)} ` with `onClick={() => this.onClick(item.name)}` does the trick! Stupid I have missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are changing the color of all the span elements, as you set for each span the style to the state variable *bgColor*.

Insteas, you should save the clicked item, and decide the color based on that:

```
this.state = {
    bgColor: 'red',
    clickedColor: 'blue
}
```

In the constructor.

Then in the click handler:

```
changeColor(item){
    this.setState({selected: item.name});

    console.log('clicked item == ' + item.name)
}
```

So in the renderer (I just put the relevant part):

```
<span ... style={{backgroundColor: (item.name === this.state.selected ? this.state.clickedColor : this.state.bgColor)}}>{`item ${index}`}</span>
```